# Django Admin change_list forcing search_form to reject given seach keywords

Tags: django, database, django-templates, django-admin

**Problem:**

I'd like to enforce the change_list_view when opening the page with "?q=" (that is with no value or whitespace) and simply load the page by not executing queries at all.

**Possible ways:**

My question is how can I do that by overriding the queryset, get_queryset, or get_search_results methods ?

Any other means are welcomed?

**Expectations:**

The end goal is to:

- start with a page displaying 0 results
- no database activity
- the search text input focused
- underneath a message instructing the user the it may start typing the thing it seeks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't override `ModelAdmin.get_queryset()` because it is used in the edit/delete views.  So you have to inherit `ChangeList` class and override `get_queryset()` in it:

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ChangeList

class MyChangeList(ChangeList):

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super(MyChangeList, self).get_queryset(request)
        if not request.GET.get('q', ''):
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Start typing.')
            queryset = queryset.none()

        return queryset


class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):
        return MyChangeList
```

Comment: Thanks for this snippet, it works fine, however, now something else is using the database too, any hints on how to find who is using the database ?

Comment: Create a model with `user`, `query`, `time` fields and modify `MyChangeList.get_queryset()` to add records to this table with `request.user`, `request.GET['q']` and `timezone.now()`,

Comment: Nevermind that, it was loading the sidebar, I could try removing the sidebar, just to load the search very fast :), then it will show up in the next page :D.